# Multiple rows in one row separated by commas with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible using stuff with xml path for multiple columns in one select? At the moment I have this:

```
SELECT
    tb.field1, tb.field2,
    STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ta.field3
           FROM @tbl ta
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM @tbl tb
```

Results

```
field1  field2   field3
----------------------------
12      3        data1,data2
15      2        data1,data2
18      12       data1,data2
20      29       data1,data2
```

And I want add more columns like field3 but without repeating the code like this for the other columns:

```
STUFF((Select Distinct ', ' + ta.field4
    from @tbl ta
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Expected results:

```
 field1  field2       field3         field4....
    -------------------------------------- 
    12      3        data1,data2      data1,data2
    15      2        data1,data2      data1,data2
    18      12       data1,data2      data1,data2
    20      29       data1,data2      data1,data2
```

Comment: If you're on a more recent version of SQL Server, consider using `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Remember that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need two subqueries:

```
SELECT . . . ,
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ta.field3
               FROM @tbl ta
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
             ) as field3s,
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + ta.field4
               FROM @tbl ta
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
             ) as field4s
```

I would expect these subqueries to have a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE a.? = b.?
```

to correlate the results to the outer query.

In more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `STRING_AGG()`, but it doesn't support `DISTINCT`, so that requires complications of its own.